# How to generate report for code review and setup process to review code while merging in TFS 2015 Update3?

Tags: tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 update3.(On-Prem)

We are using code review in Microsoft Visual Studio professional 2015(Team Explorer/My work) and other through Web Access. But my questions are:

1) For Audit purpose I suppose to generate report for Code Reviews from Collection/project level. Is it possible?

2) How to mandate/restrict Code review to be setup before Merge/branch occurred in TFS 2015. If there is a way, can you provide the steps?

3)If there is a way to setup code review before merge how setup the process?

Thanks,

GSR

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For the code review report, this is probably going to be hard. Not all of the information you want is in the workflow, so you can't really report based on that. Reference [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3f2b05f7-cf11-4a0c-9212-9af922d5a819/reporting-on-code-review-results-in-tfsvs-2012?forum=tfsreporting).

Basically there isn't a way to mandate/restrict Code review to be setup before Merge/branch unless develop your own custom policy (Reference [this article](https://blog.devart.com/creating-tfs-custom-check-in-policy-part-1.html)).

However you can set the policy to enforce code review before check-in. Thus all the changes will be force reviewed before merge/branch.

To enforce code review before check-in you can install the extension on your Visual Studio client:[Colin's ALM Checkin Policies VS 2015 and VSO](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ColinD.ColinsALMCheckinPoliciesVS2015andVSO).

**To add a check-in policy:**

1. From **Team Explorer**, select the **Settings** page, then select **Source
   Control** under the Team Project section.
2. The Source Control Settings dialog box appears. Click the **Check-in
   Policy** tab and then click **Add**. The Add Check-in Policy dialog box appears.
3. In the Check-in Policy list, select the policy type you want and
   then click OK.

[image]